# JSP, Tomcat 8 BASIC login / failed attempt keeps being persistent

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, authentication, browser-cache

**Problem 1**

When a user attempt to gain access to restricted files he / she does not have a role for, a HTTP-403 is given back to the user.

When than trying to re-login using the same link (BASIC authentication) to type different credentials, the failed login attempt is remembered and goes directly to an HTTP-403, without asking for username / password.

**Problem 2**

When a user succesfully login and get his / her session terminated, click the login button again they arent asked to type in their login credentials because their previous login "session" is remembered.

To try and fix this behavior i have tried different solutions ALL without luck

**Solution 1**

Call the `.invalidate()` method on the `request.getSession(false)` object

**Solution 2**

Disable browser cache through a filter for all *.jsp pages on requests

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies
```

Which i found here

[Add an Expires or a Cache-Control header in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055268/add-an-expires-or-a-cache-control-header-in-jsp)

[How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)

**Solution 3**

Disabling Tomcat 8 cache in /META-INF/context.xml

```
antiJARLocking="true"
antiResourceLocking="true"
cachingAllowed="false"
cacheMaxSize ="0"
cacheTTL="1"
reloadable="false"
```

Found here

[how to disable tomcat caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743136/how-to-disable-tomcat-caching)

Undeploy, redeploy project and restart Tomcat.

For everything i have tried i have disabled browser cache such as solution 2, cleared my test browser before login test and tried private browser windows.

**Redirect back to login at error**

When i get the HTTP-403 error i call a servlet through web.xml that send the user back to the frontpage (where the login link is)

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>403</error-code>
   <location>/Http403</location>
  </error-page>
```

Through a `response.sendRedirect(url)` instead of a forward, as to force the browser to make a 'fresh' HTTP-GET for the frontpage / welcomepage. I read somewhere that this was the way to do it but not 100% if this is has any advantage or not, if someone knows please let me know.

**Found the problem**

From [Basic Authentication : Is it possible to setRemoteUser like getRemoteUser()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225564/basic-authentication-is-it-possible-to-setremoteuser-like-getremoteuser)

The BASIC authentication is a completely different thing. It shows a bare JavaScript look-a-like dialog with username/password inputs. It stores the authentication information on the **client side which get sent as a request header on every single subsequent request**

Answer (score 0):

I think a filter can solve this problem, if a user does not hava a role, redirect to login page, otherwise he/she could access the resource in server

Comment: How would you test if the user has the correct role / roles or not?

Comment: Also how would you call the filter and redirect the request before the requested resources is tried accessed and makes the HTTP-403?

Comment: tomcat would call the filter when someone try to access a resource that matches `url-parttern` that you can configure in `web-xml`.

Comment: In my edit  2 of the original post i have tried to call the filter through the url-pattern for the restricted area, and no options i use lets me trigger the filter before the BASIC authentication.

Comment: when a user login, I used call HttpSession.setAttribute(), so when a user try to access resources , so i can tell if the user has correct role . I don't know if i misunderstood your words. My English ....... poor